# Button's IsEnabled property depends on Command property?

Tags: wpf, button, isenabled

I am surprised by the following behavior of Button.

I have created a usercontrol for button + image.

```
<UserControl x:Name="root">
    <Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand, ElementName=root}" Click="Button_Click">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, ElementName=root, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Stretch="None" />
            <TextBlock Padding="4,0"
                       Text="{Binding Caption, ElementName=root, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

The `ClickEvent` and `ClickCommandProperty` are in code-behind as RoutedEvent and DependencyProperty.

It works as expected, but I do not understand why the UserControl **cannot be enabled** when I do not set the `ClickCommand` in xaml at least to an empty string.

```
<c:ImageButton Caption="Refresh" Click="refresh_Click" x:Name=btnRefresh
               ClickCommand="" ImageSource="{StaticResource refresh}" />
```

So without `ClickCommand=""` the code `btnRefresh.IsEnabled = true;` has no effect.
Also: the `IsEnabledChanged` event is invoked by `.IsEnabled = true;` and not again to set it to false? Mysteries.

Comment: Mysterious indeed. Does your user control have a command attached to the button that has a CanClick? And if so, is there something that makes it always return false whenever the clickcommand dependecyproperty is modified?

Comment: Probably the correct direction. It turns out then when I use `ClickCommand=""`  the ClickCommand property is null. When I omit `ClickCommand=""` the ClickCommand property is set and `CanExecute(null, null)` evaluates to false. At least that's something albeit not very logical.

Comment: I just adjusted your title... hope you don't mind. Is your `ClickCommand` property of type `ICommand`?

Comment: No it is of type `RoutedCommand`. As a matter of fact I may have to change that, until now I only tested the `RoutedEvent`. Thks Sheridan for correcting.

Comment: What is a ClickCommand in ImageButton? Is that a custom control? I know that Button has as Command but that one is new to me. However, I would say the one who implemented that ClickCommand did something very unusual.

Comment: @dev hedgehog See above, I did not yet test the ClickCommand and may have to change it to ICommand. However the ClickEvent works fine.

Comment: Implement ICommandSource in your UserControl and you shall do fine. :)